# Is it less expensive to serve signed or unsigned URLS from Google Storage?

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I am storing user uploaded images in Google Cloud storage that will frequently be downloaded and served by users on iOS devices. I have noticed that signed URL's have expiration dates while unsigned URL's do not.

It seems that in my use case URL's without expiration dates are preferred. This is because I do not want to risk a user that opens the app after X days while it was running in the background opens an expired URL.

I am deciding whether to send signed or unsigned URL's to the client and will only choose signed URL's if using unsigned URL's are more expensive.

Is it more expensive to serve unsigned URL's that have no expiration date?

Comment: Expensive by what measurement?

Comment: @DougStevenson in terms of bandwith, computation, or overall cost that google charges you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no cost difference for serving signed URLs. You should make the decision whether to use them based on your application requirements.

Comment: Ok, I will proceed to use unsigned URL's without expiration. Thanks.